# Controlling Network Settings in IOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios

I have a project where it's highly desired to have some control over network settings in IOS 5 for an iPad device.  The ideal scenario would be to have to ability to change the device's wifi connection to a specific SSID.  My gut tells me that this is probably functionality that isn't exposed in the SDK but I figured I'd ask.

An alternate goal, if my first assumption about directly changing a connection is correct, would be to allow the app to prompt the user to change network settings and direct the user to the settings screen.  I've seen a handful of apps offer this when, for example, the device is in airplane mode and the app requires an internet connection.  The major difference in my case is that I'm not necessarily looking to prompt the user just when the device is not on the internet but when whatever connection the device already may (or may not) have isn't the one I'm looking for (in this case, I'm looking for a closed/non-internet-facing Wifi ssid on an aircraft).

I appreciate any pointers that can lead me in the right direction.

Comment: All of what you want is unable in the SDK, except you can open the settings app using the preferences URL scheme

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that iOS 5.1 removes the ability to open settings from an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not fit perfectly what you want but I think [CaptiveNetwork](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html) is the closest you can get.

The API bindings for CaptiveNetwork are available in recent MonoTouch releases.

Comment: Thanks poupou.  I have been looking into CaptiveNetwork and it's what I've been using to detect the WiFi SSID to determine if certain operations are available to the user.  As expected, though, it this framework doesn't seem to offer the ability to actually direct the device to a specific SSID.  Unfortunately, I gathered from researching the topic of opening network settings from an app that this is something that is not allowed (worked around in iOS 5.0 with OpenUrl to the prefs page until Apple shut that down in 5.1).